# How to set AUTHORIZATION on CREATE SCHEMA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, schema

I'm looking to create a new schema for an existing database, which currently only uses the `dbo` schema. I'm after advice on how to set the `AUTHORIZATION` (owner name) and what affect this will have.

**1. Should I create a new user for this or can I use the `dbo` user?**

I notice the existing `Database Roles` in the database are owned by the `dbo` user.

**2. If I set the `AUTHORIZATION` to a new user will I need to create new `Database Roles` owned by the new user?**

I've also noticed the `Default schema` for existing `Users` is the `dbo` schema.

**3. Will I need to create new `Users` with a default schema set to the new schema?**

My main reason for creating the new schema is to separate the database objects by name rather than for permissions. I intend on granting certain existing `Users` access to specific database procedures on the new schema as we do for database procedures on the dbo schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate the other answers but am posting an answer now to pass on the understanding I now have from various sources:

**1. Should I create a new user for this or can I use the dbo user?**

As per [JasonBluefire's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/253750/169177) the dbo user may be used when adding the schema for organisational reasons rather than as segregation for security purposes. Once the schema is created this relationship may be seen using the following query:

```
SELECT s.schema_id, s.name, 
    dp.principal_id, dp.name, dp.type_desc
FROM sys.schemas s 
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON s.principal_id = dp.principal_id
```

**2. If I set the AUTHORIZATION to a new user will I need to create new Database Roles owned by the new user?**

The only significance of the dbo ownership of the database roles is that *"The owner of the role, or any member of an owning role can add or remove members of the role."*. See [CREATE ROLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql) MS documentation. There's therefore no need to create new versions of the existing database roles.

**3. Will I need to create new Users with a default schema set to the new schema?**

The only significance of the default schema being set to dbo for existing database users is that it will be *"the first schema that will be searched by the server when it resolves the names of objects for this database user."*. See [CREATE USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) MS documentation. There's therefore no need to create new users.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a new user to be owner of the schema.

The default dbo owner is fine, especially if your adding the schema for organization reasons rather then security.

You do not need to create new users to access the new schema.

The only thing I would add is to make sure if you do change the owner from dbo, you change it to a domain service account or other permanent sql account. If the user gets deleted it can cause issues accessing the schema.

Comment: Also see [changing schema ownership and side effects](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76843/changing-schema-ownership-and-side-effects?rq=1) on why switching owners can get sticky.

Answer (score 0):

Just create each schema, leave the owner as .dbo unless you have another **permanent** 'SA' type account that you wanted to house them under.  Then just assign access to them accordingly by user name.  You don't need to create anything other than the schema you want and assign the rights.